# jQuery Selectors - "this" or "data"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select a bunch of individual elements. I have done simple jquery with addClass, toggleClass, removeClass and I have that down pretty well. But if I continue down this path, my JS will be a ton of .click functions with toggleClass.

**How can I target only one element at a time?** Currently it opens all three of the picker elements. Eventually, this will build out into something larger but for this part, I need to target specific elements in a more generic way. I think that the data attributes need to be stored in a variable, or something, and then referenced that way when selecting the element on click. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
  $('.picker .pick').toggleClass('show');
  $('.picker .container header').toggleClass('minus');
});
```

```css
.picker {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.picker {
    width: 20%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.picker .container {
    width: 100%;
}

.picker .container header {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: .4s ease-in;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.picker .container header.minus:after,
.picker .container header:after {
    font-family: fontawesome;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.picker .container header:after {
 content: "\f055";
}

.picker .container header.minus:after {
    content: "\f056";
}

.picker .pick {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="picker">

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="buildit">Build Your Own Site:</h1>
  </div>


  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR MENU ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Menu Style:</header>
    <div class="navpick pick" data-pick="navpicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="fixedtop">Fixed Top</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="statictop">Static Top Navbar</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="static">Static Navbar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR HERO ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Hero Style:</header>
    <div class="heropick pick" data-pick="heropicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="bggifness">Background GIF</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="bgvid">Background Video</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="narrow">Fixed Width</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="jumbo">Jumbotron</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="slider">Slider</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR LAYOUT ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Layout:</header>
    <div class="layoutpick pick" data-pick="layoutpicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="magazine">Magazine</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod2">2 product</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod3">3 product</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod4">4 product</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `this` and the `next()` method to target only the immediately-following element:

```
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.pick').toggleClass('show');
  $(this).toggleClass('minus');
});
```

Or chain the operations:

```
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('minus').next('.pick').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.picker .container header').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('minus').next('.pick').toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.picker {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.picker {
  /* width: 20%; */
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.picker .container {
  width: 100%;
}
.picker .container header {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: .4s ease-in;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.picker .container header.minus:after,
.picker .container header:after {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.picker .container header:after {
  content: "\f055";
}
.picker .container header.minus:after {
  content: "\f056";
}
.picker .pick {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="picker">

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="buildit">Build Your Own Site:</h1>
  </div>


  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR MENU ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Menu Style:</header>
    <div class="navpick pick" data-pick="navpicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="fixedtop">Fixed Top</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="statictop">Static Top Navbar</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="static">Static Navbar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR HERO ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Hero Style:</header>
    <div class="heropick pick" data-pick="heropicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="bggifness">Background GIF</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="bgvid">Background Video</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="narrow">Fixed Width</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="jumbo">Jumbotron</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="slider">Slider</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR LAYOUT ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Layout:</header>
    <div class="layoutpick pick" data-pick="layoutpicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="magazine">Magazine</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod2">2 product</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod3">3 product</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod4">4 product</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: This is it—using `$(this)` to establish context is the simplest way to achieve what you want ;) +1. p/s: Would it be even better if you edit OP's code snippet and include it in your answer to show that your code is functional?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can solve this. But in your case, using the `$(".picker .pick")` selector, will return three elements. You need to filter this down to individual elements.

For example, if you wanted to target only the first element, you could use the `:eq` selector

```
$(".picker .pick:eq(0)").toggleClass('show');
```

Or through traversing

```
$(".picker .pick").eq(0).toggleClass('show')
```

Or you could use the `find` property and search for the class `pick`

```
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.pick').toggleClass('show');
}
```

Or using the `filter` function

```
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
    $(this).filter('.pick').toggleClass('show');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being so thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $pick = $('.pick', $this.parent());
    $pick.toggleClass('show');
    $this.toggleClass('minus');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
  $('.picker .pick').toggleClass('show');
  $('.picker .container header').toggleClass('minus');
});


$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('minus'); //toggle only the header you have clicked on
  $(this).find('.pick').toggleClass('show'); // toggle only .picks inside the header you have clicked on
   //or $('.pick', $(this)).toggleClass('show');
});
```

This could be made slightly better by not using find inside a click function

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `$(this)` to get the clicked element, and exclude it with `not($(this))` from the second selection.

This is the code you need:

```
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('show');
      $('.picker .container header').not($(this)).toggleClass('minus');
});
```

```js
$('.picker .container header').click(function() {
  console.log($(this));
  $(this).toggleClass('show');
  $('.picker .container header').not($(this)).toggleClass('minus');
});
```

```css
.picker {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.picker {
    width: 20%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.picker .container {
    width: 100%;
}

.picker .container header {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: .4s ease-in;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.picker .container header.minus:after,
.picker .container header:after {
    font-family: fontawesome;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.picker .container header:after {
 content: "\f055";
}

.picker .container header.minus:after {
    content: "\f056";
}

.picker .pick {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="picker">

  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="buildit">Build Your Own Site:</h1>
  </div>


  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR MENU ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Menu Style:</header>
    <div class="navpick pick" data-pick="navpicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="fixedtop">Fixed Top</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="statictop">Static Top Navbar</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="static">Static Navbar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR HERO ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Hero Style:</header>
    <div class="heropick pick" data-pick="heropicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="bggifness">Background GIF</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="bgvid">Background Video</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="narrow">Fixed Width</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="jumbo">Jumbotron</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="slider">Slider</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- ********** PICK YOUR LAYOUT ********** -->
  <div class="container">
    <header>Pick Your Layout:</header>
    <div class="layoutpick pick" data-pick="layoutpicker">
      <ul>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="magazine">Magazine</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod2">2 product</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod3">3 product</li>
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="prod4">4 product</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I have never seen "not($(this))" before. Interesting. I will try that with the rest of this project.

Comment: @SamLuedke This is the [jQuery **.not()** Docs page](http://api.jquery.com/not/) , yes it's fantastic.